# Using Delete as header

Tags: sql, csv

I am using Text_JDBC40 jar and trying to fetch data from a csv file using sql query. In the csv file I have a header named as **Delete** so when I am trying to fetch data I am getting the below error.

> **Syntax error:  Stopped parse at Delete**

Renaming this column with some other name fetches the data properly. Any idea why this is happening? Also is there any other option for Text_JDBC40 jar?

Comment: DELETE might be a reserved word.

Comment: Yes, I thought that too but did not find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to import data into sql from csv then Delete quoted with Grave accent(`)   while creating and retrieving the data. Please try this, may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. This resolved the issue. Any idea why this may be happening apart from that being a keyword?

Comment: @KshitishSC, this problem occurs only when we use sql reserved keywords( not keywords). If we use keywords it's ok, but shouldn't use reserved keyword without accent symbol.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful.

Comment: I just realized that I am using apostrophe(') and not grave accent(`) and apostrophe is working for me but not grave accent.